# RequireJS/Backbone : inheritance of dependencies?

Tags: inheritance, backbone.js, requirejs, dependency-management, resthub

**Update :** I've found a solution which is slighty the same as in the first answer. **But in fact I'd like to know if there is a manner using RequireJS, to do that without using special var or parameters in views**. Here is my solution :

```
define(['resthub', 'backbone', 'views/myModule/parent-view', 'views/myModule/a-view'],
function(Resthub, Backbone, ParentView, AView) {

    var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({

        // Stuff before

        buildAView : function(aViewObject){
            var aView = aViewObject || AView;

            // Enought source code before and after those following lines
            // that I don't want to duplicate in ChildView
            this.aView = new aView();
            this.aView.render();
        }

        // Stuff after

    });

    return ParentView;
});
```

---

I try to use a maximum the inheritance in a Backbone project which dependencies are managed by RequireJS to avoid duplicate code.
In fact, I create a new view that extend a base view. The base view has a dependency that I want to override. But even if i try to override, the original dependency is taken, instead of the new one. Note than I'm forced to inherit.

Here what I'm trying to do :

Base view I inherit :

```
define(['resthub', 'backbone', 'views/myModule/parent-view', 'views/myModule/a-view'],
function(Resthub, Backbone, ParentView, AView) {

    var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({

        // Stuff before

        buildAView : function(){
            // Enought source code before and after those following lines
            // that I don't want to duplicate in ChildView
            this.aView = new AView();
            this.aView.render();
        }

        // Stuff after

    });

    return ParentView;
});
```

Then view i attempt to create. What I want is that buildAView() function takes the new dependency called AView in b-view which contains not the same source code as in a-view.

```
define(['resthub', 'backbone', 'views/myModule/parent-view', 'views/myModule/b-view'],
function(Resthub, Backbone, ParentView, AView) {

    var ChildView = ParentView.extend({

        // Stuff before

        render: function() {

            ParentView.__super__.render.apply(this, []);

            /* some stuff inbetween*/

            this.buildAView();
        }

    });

    return ChildView;
});
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `AView` is bound to the function it was injected, so when you call the `buildAView` it use the `AView` that was injected into the `ParentView` module. But there is a simple way to fix the problem. Just save `AView` as property of your view.

```
define(['resthub', 'backbone', 'views/myModule/parent-view', 'views/myModule/a-view'],
function(Resthub, Backbone, ParentView, AView) {

    var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({

        // Stuff before
        AView: AView,

        buildAView : function(){
            // Enought source code before and after those following lines
            // that I don't want to duplicate in ChildView
            this.aView = new this.AView();
            this.aView.render();
        }

        // Stuff after

    });

    return ParentView;
});

define(['resthub', 'backbone', 'views/myModule/parent-view', 'views/myModule/b-view'],
function(Resthub, Backbone, ParentView, AView) {

    var ChildView = ParentView.extend({

        // Stuff before
        AView: AView,

        render: function() {

            ParentView.__super__.render.apply(this, []);

            /* some stuff inbetween*/

            this.buildAView();
        }

    });

    return ChildView;
});
```

Comment: I figured out it was a problem of scope. In fact, I wanted to know if there was another way, using RequireJS, to do that without a var containing my AView ?
Since my answer I've been working on a similar way you propose : buildAView function can receive a parameter, that is used in place of AView object if given in ParentView, otherwise, original AView from ParentView's define is used. See my original post.